# Can I use simple types in template sorting

Tags: java, sorting, types

I am learning sorting now, and didn't understand something.
 My sort is working with classes Integer, Double... etc, but not with types int, short, long, double etc.
 I used `public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sexySort(T[] a)` 
 And `public static <T extends Number> void sexySort(T[] a)`.

P.S. I have tried with reflect, but still not working
`public static <T> int checkClass(T t){
        String type = t.getClass().getCanonicalName();
        if(type.equals("java.lang.Integer")){
            return 0;
        }
        else if(type.equals("java.lang.Double")){
            return 1;
        }
        return -1;
        //etc.
    }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use Java generics effectively, you must consider the following restrictions:

- Cannot Instantiate Generic Types with Primitive Types
- Cannot Create Instances of Type Parameters
- Cannot Declare Static Fields Whose Types are Type Parameters
- Cannot Use Casts or instanceof With Parameterized Types
- Cannot Create Arrays of Parameterized Types
- Cannot Create, Catch, or Throw Objects of Parameterized Types
- Cannot Overload a Method Where the Formal Parameter Types of Each Overload Erase to the Same Raw Type

Reference: [see example in Java tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html#instantiate)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use primitive types as "template" parameters (Parameterized Types in Java).

[JLS-4.5 Parameterized Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.5),

> It is a compile-time error if C is not the name of a generic class or interface, or if the number of type arguments in the type argument list differs from the number of type parameters of C.

and explicitly in the examples states that

> primitive types cannot be type arguments.